# If Post values equal other than other post values echo"failed";?

Tags: php, sql

I have two combo boxes, one to report scores and one to set who scored the goals, How can i make it so if on post['submit']

If $_POST['Score1'] and $_POST['Score2']
is other than equal to
$_POST['homegoalscorer1'] and $_POST['awaygoalscorer1']
then echo"fail";

Something like;

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))   
 {
 $homescore = $_POST['Score1'];
 $awayscore = $_POST['Score2'];

 $homegoalscorer = $_POST['homegoalscorer1'];
 $awaygoalscorer =  $_POST['awaygoalscorer1'];

   if '$homescore' + '$awayscore' != $homegoalscorer + $awaygoalscorer {
      echo "failed";
   }
      else {

            }
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not looked at the rest of the problem yet, but `'$homescore' + '$awayscore'` should be $homescore + $awayscore, lose the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes on a variable will turn that variable intro a string without execution. Also you forgot to add brackets:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))   {
    $homescore = (float)$_POST['Score1'];
    $awayscore = (float)$_POST['Score2'];

    $homegoalscorer = (float)$_POST['homegoalscorer1'];
    $awaygoalscorer =  (float)$_POST['awaygoalscorer1'];

    if (($homescore+$awayscore) != ($homegoalscorer+$awaygoalscorer)) {
        echo "failed";
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some brackets in your if statement to force the conditional setting in the correct context - and why are you encapsulating your variables in single quotes?

```
if (($homescore + $awayscore) != ($homegoalscorer + $awaygoalscorer))
{
// Your code continues....
```